What is the best way to level shift 50kHz 3.3V PWM signal to 5V PWM signal output
I’m working on an STM32F103 microcontroller (3.3V logic) and need to drive 5V PWM signals for BLDC fans at 50kHz. I’m looking for a reliable and cost-effective solution to level shift the 3.3V PWM to 5V. So far, I’ve considered two options:

Using a MOSFET for level shifting
Using an opamp

Which option would be better in terms of cost, simplicity, and performance? Also, if there's a more industrial-grade approach that’s commonly used in such applications, I’d really appreciate the insight. Looking for something that can handle production requirements as well.
Thanks in advance!

An op-amp, particularly a cost-effective op-amp, is a very poor choice for this application. The cheap ones won't drive within 1.5V of the power rails.  Even one that's specifically designed for 5V supply and rail-to-rail operation will tend to perform poorly close to the rails.  There's plenty of cheap options to do what you want -- don't even think about using an op-amp here.

Likely neither is a good option but something else. The exact details of the signal required by BLDC fans is needed for correct method. Some fans require push pull output, some require open-drain. What kind of signal your fans require?

There's a simpler answer: logic level shifters, and logic families with suitable input thresholds.
74HCT family logic is compatible with 3.3V LVCMOS logic levels.  Any device from that family can be used: buffer; AND, OR, XOR, etc. with inputs strapped as needed; NOT if you don't mind negating the PWM setting, or use two in series.  A 5V supply is needed.
A single MOSFET, or BJT, with pull-up resistor, affords the right voltage levels, but only a weak pull-up; check the fan datasheet to see how much current (if any) is drawn by its input pin.  BSS138, MMBT3904 (with external bias resistors), DDC114EU (includes bias resistors), and friends are all suitable here.
An op-amp is less preferable, because it's more expensive (an RRO type is required), and has limited response speed which compromises PWM accuracy at min/max range.  The slew rate might also be unsuitable for use as a logic signal, and the output isn't suitable (or without additional components) to drive long lines/cables, if that is applicable.
If a 5V supply is not handy, consider using a pull-up resistor (again, check pin current requirements) to a higher supply (12, 24V, whatever), use the open-collector/drain transistor solution, and clamp the output with a 5.6V zener diode.


What is the best way to level shift 50kHz 3.3V PWM signal to 5V PWM
signal output

Many situations like this exist where a 5 volt device can quite reasonably directly connect its input to a logic level of 3.3 volts and work with no problem.
So, it boils down to what the input specification is for the device you wish to drive. As an example, a typical TTL compatible signal is this: -

Image from here. Can you see that if your device has TTL compatible inputs, a 3.3 volt logic level will be fine. If it doesn't have a TTL compatible input then you may need to use a buffer that is.

There are dedicated Voltage translators & level shifters ICs.
Given the question mentions converting from 3.3 V logic to a 5 V PWM, and contains the automotive tag perhaps a TXU0101-Q1 which is a Automotive single-channel fixed-direction level shifter. From the features:

It supports the required input and output voltages:

Fully configurable dual-rail design allows each port to operate from 1.1 V to 5.5 V


Supports more than the required 50 kHz frequency:

Up to 200 Mbps support for 3.3 V to 5.0 V


Protection against a floating input:

Inputs with integrated static pull-down resistors prevent channels from floating


While the question doesn't mention the required drive strength for the PWM output, the TXU0101-Q1 is described as:

High drive strength (up to 12 mA at 5 V)




May work, but many times more expensive than a comparable simpler part. Also as a safety mechanism and powerup sequencing, if there is no PWM input, fans pull the PWM pin high to be 100% on.

I think you can use this circuit (inverting so 100% is off):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Some fans will directly accept a 3.3V signal, but not all.
